# Remove "Generator" meta tag?

Tags: 8, meta-tags

How can I remove the *Generator* meta-tag in Drupal 8?

```html
<meta name="Generator" content="Drupal 8 (https://www.drupal.org)" />
```

Can this be done with few lines of code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basing on the patch provided in [Remove Generator META tag & X-Generator for Drupal 8 version!](https://www.drupal.org/node/2676164) this is the code that would achieve that.

```php
/**
 * Implements hook_page_attachments_alter().
 */
function HOOK_page_attachments_alter(array &$attachments) {
  foreach ($attachments['#attached']['html_head'] as $key => $attachment) {
    if ($attachment[1] == 'system_meta_generator') {
      unset($attachments['#attached']['html_head'][$key]);
    }
  }
}
```